# PHP - Test if $_GET value is one of the following

Tags: php, get

First ever question on stackoverflow (new user) so bare with me.

I have a website **[www.website.com/?view=overview](http://www.website.com/?view=overview)** .

I want to test if VIEW exists, if it does not then I redirect to another page
(this is done with empty($_GET['view') **and works**

If that test passes, I now want to get that view is one of 5 values, if it is then I allow the user to continue if not I redirect to another page.

I have tried with a variable and array, with in_array and the most I can get it to do is properly recognize a single value. When I try to test for more than one, it always redirects. Here is the example if I am testing for two values (overview and settings) but again the total number tested should be 5.

```
if (empty($_GET['view'])) {
            header("Location: www.website.com/?view=overview");
    } else {
        if (($_GET['view'] != "overview") || ($_GET['view'] != "settings")) {
            header("Location: www.website.com/?view=overview");
        } 
    }
}
```

I searched everywhere and I am stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using || (OR) when you should be using && (AND)

```
if (empty($_GET['view'])) {
            header("Location: www.website.com/?view=overview");
    } else {
        if (($_GET['view'] != "overview") && ($_GET['view'] != "settings")) {
            header("Location: www.website.com/?view=overview");
        } 
    }
}
```

If `$_GET['view']` equals 'settings' then it's not equal to 'overview', that part of the condition will pass and your code will redirect. And vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I hope this will help someone in the future.

My logic was that the test would say "If $_GET['view'] is not X *or* Y .. etc etc then it would check them individually and if i was to use *and* that it would try to satisfy all criteria at the same time.

I understand the logic now that we are basically doing a SINGLE test for a multitude of variable and thats why its AND and not OR.


PS. I do not have enough reputation to cast a vote but I tried to give it a USEFUL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array(needle, haystack)` having a list of valid values:

```
$valid_views = ['overview', 'settings'];
if (!in_array($_GET['view'], $valid_views){
   header("Location: www.website.com/?view=overview");
} else {
   // view is ok, continue
   header("Location: www.website.com/?view=".$_GET['view']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was putting the $_GET outside of the in_array!

PS. I do not have enough reputation to cast a vote but I tried to give it a USEFUL.